# Why should $\theta(s)$ be a smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, plane-curves

While I was trying to read some Differential Geometry, I came upon this question:

> Let $T(s)$ be the unit tangent vector field on a plane curve $\gamma(s)$ parametrized by arc length. Write $$T(s) =\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta(s)\\ \sin \theta(s)\end{bmatrix}$$
> where $\theta(s)$ is the angle of $T(s)$ with respect to the positive horizontal axis. Show that the signed curvature $\kappa$ is the derivative $d\theta/ ds$.

I can see how $\kappa$ will be $d\theta/ ds$ if $\theta(s)$ is smooth but I don't see how to prove the smoothness (or atleast differentiability) of $\theta(s)$.

**My attempt :** I tried to compose inverse trigonometric functions with $T(s)$ to get $\theta(s)$ but that didn't seem to work, as, in getting an actual smooth function that maps into $\mathbb{R}$ that gives the angle, there is some arbitrary choice as to what branch of angle is being choosed.

Can someone please help?

Comment: If you know the concept of lifts, then $\theta$ is smooth because of the following argument: you have a function $T: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle. Considering the covering map $\pi: \mathbb{R} \to S^1, \pi(t) = e^{it}$, by the lifting criterion, you have that there is a smooth function $\theta : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $T = \pi \circ \theta$, i.e. $T(s) = e^{i\theta(s)} = (\cos(\theta(s)), \sin(\theta(s)))$.

Comment: Thank you, for the help! I was only aware of the topological version of lifts (where the maps are only continuous and not smooth). Can you suggest some reference for reading about smooth lifts?

Comment: You can find the "usual concepts" about "smooth lifts" (also smooth covering maps and quotient maps) in Lee's Smooth Manifolds, 2nd edition, Chapter 4.

Comment: Nice! Thanks again.

Comment: Since, for each $s$, there are many possible values for $\theta(s)$, the function $\theta$ need not be smooth. However, what you can show is that given a value for $\theta(s_0)$, there is a unique way to extend $\theta$ to be a smooth function on an open interval containing $s_0$.

Comment: @Deane Sorry for the late reply. But I thought for a given point $e$ in the pre image of $T(s)$ under the covering map $\pi$, there exists a unique (continuous) lift $\theta$ for $T$ such that $\pi (e) = T(s)$. It seems that proving that this $\theta$ is smooth is possible in our case (Which was what I thought C_M indicated in the comments.) So basically, a smooth lift is possible right? Or is there some mistake here?

Comment: Yes, a smooth lift is possible. That's what I tried to say.

Comment: Ah sorry, I think I misunderstood the comment then. Thanks!